# 'hosts' file in 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc' automatically renamed to 'tmphosts'

Tags: iis-7, hosts

I am using hosts file in 'etc' directory on IIS7. I am experiecing a very strange problem. The hosts file automatically renamed to tmphosts after an uncertain period of time. Usually after rebooting my computer, sometimes in between the work.

I ran Microsoft Fix for this, but problem persists.

I had tried with Disabling AntiVirus but no luck.

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how is this a programming related question which is what StackOverflow is about?

Comment: probably a virus or something messing with that file. normal day-to-day operations should never be touching that file.

Comment: You can name it back by opening the file as an administrator, then save-as. As for why it's being re-named, not sure. Sorry.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I've checked many IIS related questions on stack overflow. This is a website deployment issue of IIS, which is more or less relates to programming.

Comment: No, you have a special site dedicated for this. It's called http://superuser.com I invite you to use it. StackOverflow is a programming related Q&A site. Here when you ask a question you should present the programming language you are using, show your code and explain the difficulties you encountered with your code. If you are unable to do so then you shouldn't be asking here. Please read the [`FAQ`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to familiarize yourself with the kind of questions you may ask here.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for inviting. Will keep this in mind before asking new questions. (All of my past questions were purely programmatic)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time if the host file contains redirection for license validation links, then the file is renamed so that next time the licensing app can connect to server. Some times it is renamed and some times the file content is deleted. I have seen both the cases.